# GGplot - multiple lines for same column value based on other column - no facets

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with three groups. I have to plot lines for some metric by group and status ---- this **cannot be faceted**. All lines must appear together in the same graph. Each group will have a line color - and two lines - one dashed and one solid based on a Boolean status i.e., for three groups there will be six lines.

A similar sample dataframe:

```
Data <- data.frame(
    groupname = sample(c("group1", "group2", "group3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
    timeblock = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE),
    supermetric = sample(1:25, 100, replace = TRUE),
    boolstatus = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE) )
```

So far I've unsuccessfully tried: to split based on groups and calling the nested elements as well as attempting to create various layers with smaller data frames (which flies in the face of all recommendations to melt data).
Errors have included:

```
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:group1df$supermetric

Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the description, I tried

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=timeblock, y=supermetric, 
                 group=interaction(boolstatus, groupname),
              colour=groupname, linetype=factor(boolstatus))) +
  geom_line()
```

but I don't know if that's the plot you wanted.

Comment: That's it. Now, I'll need to smooth the lines. Thank you.